# Conditions for $\Gamma_f(\lambda) = \int P^{\lambda}f$ to be analytic in $\Re (\lambda) >0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

In his book about Rings of Differential Operators, Björk mentions the following:

Let $f\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and let $P(x_1,...,x_n)$ be a real valued and $\geq 0$ polynomial. We define the complex function $\Gamma_f(\lambda) =\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}P^{\lambda}f$. The function $\Gamma_f$ is analytic in the half-space $\Re (\lambda)> 0$.

My work in the matter has to do with some algebraic methods Björk later uses to extend the function $\Gamma_f$, and I do not know the process followed to conclude that this function is analytic, but my question is:

Would this statement still hold if $f$ was any function in the Schwartz's class $\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: you need conditions for which $\frac{d}{d\lambda}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}P^{\lambda}f=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\lambda P^{\lambda-1}f, \Re \lambda >0$ and usually this follows from DCT (as the condition on the real part imply absolute convergence of the integral at the zeroes for generic $P$, you need to worry about infinity only) so as long as you can apply it (like when $f\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the result follows

Comment: Good point. Would the condition then be that $|\lambda P(x) ^{\lambda - 1}f(x) |\leq g(x)$ for all $\lambda, x$, where $g\in \mathcal{L}^1$? Or, what is the condition that $C_0^{\infty}$ satisfies that makes it possible to apply DCT?

Comment: You need only for $\lambda$ in compacts and all $x$ as that assures analyticity